# Python webdriver can not connect localhost

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
url='http://localhost/first/'
url2='http://localhost/next/'
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 0)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.cache.offline.enable", False)
fp.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get(url2)
```

I have try to disable the cache and proxy but still can not connect localhost again , anyone know how to do,thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Yes,no response was get

Comment: Could you please try with port 8080? localhost:8080